# Python - split value to two integers

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, split, integer

What is the most optimal way to split this key/value of dictionary:

```
test_status: "2200/2204(99%)"
```

so that I get two keys whose values are integers:

```
test_status_excpected: 2204
test_status_got: 2200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split using `/` and `(` as separators.

The first value is what is left of `/`

The second value is what is right of `/` and left of `(`

Then cast the result into an int

```
myDict["test_status_excpected"] = int(myDict["test_status"].split("/")[0])
myDict["test_status_got"] = int(myDict["test_status"].split("/")[1].split("(")[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pair = {'test_status': '2200/2204(99%)'}

for key, value in pair.items():
    value = value[:9] # this will keep first 9 char which drops (99%) part
    years = value.split("/")
    new_pair = {
        "test_status_excpected": years[1],
        "test_status_got": years[0]
    }

print(new_pair)
# output: {'test_status_excpected': '2204', 'test_status_got': '2200'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string using index.

```
test_status_expected = dic_name["test_status"][:4]
test_status_got = dic_name["test_status"][5:9]
```

If you are not sure about the index, you can use like:

```
test_status_expected = dic_name["test_status"][:dic_name["test_status"].index("/")]
test_status_got = dic_name["test_status"][dic_name["test_status"].index("/")+1:dic_name["test_status"].index("(")]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *re* module. For example:

```
import re
test_status = "2200/2204(99%)"
m = re.findall('\d+', test_status)
print(m[0], m[1])
```

**Output:**

```
2200 2204
```

**Note:**

This code implicitly assumes that at least two sequences of digits will be found in the string